# Reference in mongoose schema

Tags: mongoose

I have two different schemas and i put it in two separate files, but the question is how do I reference the Schema object Id? from one file to another.

This is basically, two schema in a single file

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose')
  , Schema = mongoose.Schema

var personSchema = Schema({
  _id     : Number,
  name    : String,
  age     : Number,
  stories : [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Story' }]
});

var storySchema = Schema({
  _creator : { type: Number, ref: 'Person' },
   title    : String,
   fans     : [{ type: Number, ref: 'Person' }]
});

var Story  = mongoose.model('Story', storySchema);
var Person = mongoose.model('Person', personSchema);
```

Two Schemas in two different files

1) person.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose')
  , Schema = mongoose.Schema

var personSchema = Schema({
  _id     : Number,
  name    : String,
  age     : Number,
  stories : [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "?" }]
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Person', personSchema);
```

2) story.js

```
 var storySchema = Schema({
  _creator : { type: Number, ref: '?' },
   title    : String,
   fans     : [{ type: Number, ref: '?' }]
});


module.exports = mongoose.model('Story', storySchema);
```

What should I put in the ref in both schema file? since both of them are in a separate file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ref properties are just strings, it does not matter that they are in separate files.

Doing the following despite them in being different files will still work:

```
var personSchema = Schema({
  _id     : Number,
  name    : String,
  age     : Number,
  stories : [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Story' }]
});

var storySchema = Schema({
  _creator : { type: Number, ref: 'Person' },
   title    : String,
   fans     : [{ type: Number, ref: 'Person' }]
});
```