# How require elements in nested object in Mongoose Schema

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, schema, nestjs

Creating a Schema I need some nested objects to be always in the data post to be saved in my DB.

I tried this way creating 2 schemas and the object `valid` is being required but I need also `valid.from` and `valid.to`to be required and this way is not working.

```
import * as mongoose from 'mongoose';

const LicenseTime = new mongoose.Schema({
  from: { type: Date, required: true },
  to: { type: Date, required: true },
});

export const LicenseSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  customer: { type: String, required: true },
  appId: { type: String, required: true },
  purchaseDate: { type: Date, required: true },
  valid: { type: LicenseTime, required: true }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

But what I was able to try, your example works. I used following schemas:

```
import { Schema } from 'mongoose';

const LicenseTime = new Schema({
  from: {
    type: Date,
    required: true,
  },
  to: {
    type: Date,
    required: true,
  },
},
{
  _id: false, // Used so mongoose/mongo doesn't create id
  id: false, // Used so mongoose/mongo doesn't create id
});

export const LicenseSchema = new Schema({
  customer: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  appId: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  purchaseDate: {
    type: Date,
    required: true,
  },
  valid: {
    type: LicenseTime,
    required: true,
  },
});
```

And by using this schema when I tried to save anything else than:

```
{
  customer: 'example customer',
  appId: 'example appId',
  purchaseDate: new Date(),
  valid: {
    to: new Date(),
    from: new Date(),
  },
}
```

the save failed.

Example: If i tried saving:

```
{
  customer: 'example customer',
  appId: 'example appId',
  purchaseDate: new Date(),
  valid: {
    to: new Date(),
  },
}
```

the code failed with:

> [Nest] 8895   - 06/12/2019, 1:42 PM   [ExceptionsHandler] Cat validation failed: valid.from: Path `from` is required., valid: Validation failed: from: Path `from` is required. +829ms
>   [0] ValidationError: Cat validation failed: valid.from: Path `from` is required., valid: Validation failed: from: Path `from` is required.
>   [0]     at new ValidationError (/home/adrian/work/try/node_modules/mongoose/lib/error/validation.js:30:11)
>   [0]     at model.Document.invalidate (/home/adrian/work/try/node_modules/mongoose/lib/document.js:2260:32)
>   [0]     at SingleNested.Subdocument.invalidate (/home/adrian/work/try/node_modules/mongoose/lib/types/subdocument.js:147:18)
>   [0]     at p.doValidate.skipSchemaValidators (/home/adrian/work/try/node_modules/mongoose/lib/document.js:2109:17)
>   [0]     at /home/adrian/work/try/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schematype.js:981:9
>   [0]     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:82:9)

And to finish, i was using following dependencies:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "@nestjs/common": "^6.0.0",
    "@nestjs/core": "^6.0.0",
    "@nestjs/mongoose": "^6.1.2",
    "@nestjs/platform-express": "^6.0.0",
    "mongoose": "^5.5.14",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.12",
    "rimraf": "^2.6.2",
    "rxjs": "^6.3.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@nestjs/testing": "^6.0.0",
    "@types/express": "^4.16.0",
    "@types/jest": "^23.3.13",
    "@types/mongoose": "^5.5.6",
    "@types/node": "^10.12.18",
    "@types/supertest": "^2.0.7",
    "concurrently": "^4.1.0",
    "jest": "^23.6.0",
    "nodemon": "^1.18.9",
    "prettier": "^1.15.3",
    "supertest": "^3.4.1",
    "ts-jest": "24.0.2",
    "ts-node": "8.1.0",
    "tsconfig-paths": "3.8.0",
    "tslint": "5.16.0",
    "typescript": "3.4.3",
    "wait-on": "^3.2.0"
  },
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to write your `LicenseSchema` this way:

```js
export const LicenseSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  customer: { type: String, required: true },
  appId: { type: String, required: true },
  purchaseDate: { type: Date, required: true },
  valid: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "LicenseTime", 
    required: true
  }
});
```

By the way, this might be a possible duplicate of [Reference in mongoose schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28005797/reference-in-mongoose-schema)

Let me know if it helps

Comment: I guess that will create and save `LicenseTime` in another collection